# host solr after creating a new collection

Tags: apache, collections, solr, solr4

I tried the example provided by the Apache Solr package. 
I was trying to create a new data collection for my own schema and configurations. 
There how should I start running Solr? When I was running the example, there was a `start.jar` in example directory to start it. Will the same jar work for my case?
If not, how to create a executable for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line on the solr install page says : "Solr already includes a working demo server in the example directory that you may use as a template" . http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall#Setup .

Even if the recomended server is tomcat i have a feeling jetty will work just as well for you. Having the index production ready is more about knowing your fields and query patterns really well, as well as optimising the index through the schema and config for speed according to those patterns